# Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh

Tags: docker, apache-flink, apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon

I have three physical nodes with docker installed on each of them. I configured Mesos,Flink,Zookeeper,Marathon and Hadoop on docker of each node. When ever I changed a docker, unfortunately, Flink UI ended up with this error:

> Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh.

I have searched a lot and not understood what is wrong with configurations.

Would you please guide me how to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. I checked Flink log in worker. I found that it is related to Zookeeper. I ran these commands to clean Zookeeper data and logs.
First, I stopped Zookeeper with this command:

```
  /home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/zkServer.sh stop
```

Then, I cleaned up Zookeeper data:

```
  /home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/zkCleanup.sh /var/lib/zookeeper/data/ -n 10
```

Also, I removed all Zookeeper logs which were in **version-2** folder.

```
  rm -rf /var/lib/zookeeper/data/version-2
```

Finally, I restarted Zookeeper in all three nodes again.

```
   /home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/zkServer.sh restart
```

I hope it was helpful for others.